# Как можно оптимизировать SQL запрос?

Tags: mysql, sql, оптимизация, подзапрос

Существует запрос к таблице `bonuses`, в котором исходя из содержимого полей `referrer_id_vk` и `promo_code_id` (одно из них равно NULL) делаются подзапросы в таблицы `referrers` (`referral_settings`) либо `promo_codes`

```
SELECT *,
            IF
            (
                referrer_id_vk, 
                IF
                (
                    (SELECT referral_first_deposit_bonus FROM `referrers` WHERE id_vk = '$id_vk'),
                    (SELECT referral_first_deposit_bonus FROM `referrers` WHERE id_vk = '$id_vk'),
                    (SELECT referral_first_deposit_bonus FROM `referral_settings` WHERE id = 1)
                ),
                (SELECT value FROM `promo_codes` WHERE id = promo_code_id)
            ) AS value 
FROM `bonuses` WHERE id_vk = '$id_vk"
```

Как видите, в коде дублируется этот подзапрос

`SELECT referral_first_deposit_bonus FROM referrers WHERE id_vk = '$id_vk'`

сначала он производится чтобы проверить есть ли значение в таблице `referrers` , если есть, то снова делает этот же запрос, чтобы уже вернуть результат, иначе делает запрос в таблицу `referral_settings` . Можно ли избежать дублирование подзапроса в этом моменте?

Comment: почему вы думаете что реально СУБД будет выполнять этот запрос дважды?

Comment: @teran я не уверен в этом, это на деле не так? то есть запрос будет выполнен первый раз, а результат будет закэширован (или типа того), а во второй раз просто взят результат?

Comment: если в MySQL можно посмотреть план выполнения запроса, то самое время это сделать и убедиться

Comment: Выбросить и переписать без подзапросов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы использовал соединение таблиц, что-то вроде этого:

```
SELECT b.*,
       IF
       (
           referrer_id_vk, 
           COALESCE(r.referral_first_deposit_bonus, rs.referral_first_deposit_bonus),
           pc.value
        ) AS value 
FROM `bonuses` b
LEFT JOIN `referrers` r on b.id_vk = r.id_vk
INNER JOIN `referral_settings` rs ON rs.id = 1
LEFT JOIN `promo_codes` pc ON pc.id = b.promo_code_id
WHERE b.id_vk = '$id_vk"
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь, отличное решение, единственно в строке                                                                 LEFT JOIN `referrers` r on b.id_vk = r.id_vk нужно так соединять b.referrer_id_vk  =  r.id_vk